# Redis Desktop Manager for Aerospike?

Tags: redis, aerospike, nosql

Is there an Aerospike tool that's similar to Redis Desktop Manager in that it can go into a host and view/edit the entries/records that's stored just on that server?

aql, which is a native Aerospike tool, is like sql, which obviously doesn't have this functionality.

[image: Aerospike Desktop Manager]

Answer (score 2):

You have [AMC](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/amc), a GUI management console, but it is not a data browser. Early stage projects and community contributions are often promoted in [Launchpad](http://www.aerospike.com/launchpad/), so you should look there.

Sounds like a good community contribution, if you're up for it.